# How to get unique value of repeated nodes using dom parser

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I have a XML having repeated nodes and I have top parse it using DOM parser. After a lot R&D I could find anything on internet which can help me. My xml looks like

```
<nos1>
  <Name>aqwer</Name>
  <class>sas</class>
  <class>xcd</class>
  <class>asd</class>
  <Name>cfg</Name>
  <Name>cfg</Name>
<nos1>
```

Any suggestion How can I parse this xml for repeated values.

Comment: How about an xslt solution?

Comment: do you want to get all uniques values or to remove duplicates?

Comment: I want to get all nodes value. Any idea how can get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use w3c dom document to parse your XML as follows:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory df = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try
    {
        DocumentBuilder db = df.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getContent().getBytes("UTF-8"));
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = db.parse(is);
        NodeList links = doc.getElementsByTagName("class");
          for(int i=0; i< links.getLength(); i++)
          {
             Node link = links.item(i);
             System.out.println(link.getTextContent());
          }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: have you test this... for my xml it returns #text.

Comment: No I have not tested it. This is just hint program for you. I used same thing before. So try it out.

Comment: I have tested this now. I changed to link.getTextContent() in printing. Here is result for class node: sas
xcd
asd

Comment: @Saiprateek - Is this acceptable answer to you? please accept if it is.

Comment: I have already use this approach but as I mention for my xml its returning #text for each node

Comment: I am getting answer what you need as I mentioned in above. Can you paste your whole code here?

Answer (score 1):

You should read all elements and after reading eliminate the duplicates via a Set. Here is an example using [XMLBeam](http://xmlbeam.org), but any other library will do.

```
public class TestMultipleElements {

@XBDocURL("resource://test.xml")
public interface Projection {
    @XBRead("/nos1/Name")
    List<String> getNames();

    @XBRead("/nos1/class")
    List<String> getClasses();

}

@Test
public void uniqueElements() throws IOException {
    Projection projection = new XBProjector().io().fromURLAnnotation(Projection.class);
    for (String name : new HashSet<String>(projection.getNames())) {
        System.out.println("Found Name:" + name);
    }
    for (String clazz : new HashSet<String>(projection.getClasses())) {
        System.out.println("Found Name:" + clazz);
    }

}
}
```

This prints out:

```
Found Name:aqwer
Found Name:cfg
Found Name:xcd
Found Name:sas
Found Name:asd
```